# How to know what web page is waiting for?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

My `window.onload` is not called and load animation is constantly rolling in browser windows. Apperently, browser is waiting for something.

How to know, what is he waiting for and where this wait was initiated?

Comment: Are you sure something else is not overriding your window.onload after it was declared? console.log(window.onload) and see what you get

Comment: You can also open the debug window and select the timeline tab, then refresh the page.

Comment: do u have google analytics on your page?